# Faddeev-Popov ghost in the Standard-Model

Tags: resource-recommendations, standard-model, gauge-theory, unitarity, ghosts

When we quantize $SU(N)$ gauge theories using the path integral formalism, we must introduce Faddeev-Popov ghosts and will appears as scalar fermions coupled to our gauge bosons in the Lagrangian of our quantized gauge theory. As the Standard Model ($SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$) is a gauge theory, I was expecting to see a contributions from ghosts of both non-abelian group $SU(3)$ and $SU(2)$ in the final Lagrangian, but never found any reference mentioning them.

I know that those ghosts are non-physical fields in the sens that they are introduce as a mathematical tool to ensure unitarity of our computations. I tried to find some proper gauge fixing to remove them but I think I'm missing something more fundamental in the construction of the SM Lagrangian as I never found any mention of a specific gauge.

I would really appreciate some references to see in depth the computations done to get ride of them.

Comment: Have you searched for "standard model lagrangian" ? https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/the-deconstructed-standard-model-equation

Comment: See Sec. 2.2.1 [here](https://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/12277/1/Infrared%20problem%20in%20the%20Faddeev--Popov%20sector%20in%20Yang--Mills%20Theory%20and%20Perturbative%20Gravity%20-%20Jos%20Gibbons%20-%20PhD%20-%202015.pdf) for a motivation of Yang-Mills theory's Nakanishi-Lautrup auxiliary field and FP-ghosts; their perturbative gravity counterparts are discussed in Sec 2.6.3 (ibid.). These refer you to Peskin and Schroeder Secs. 9.4 and 16.2, Kugo and Ojima 1979, Ojima 1980 etc.